# How to get the age of a Web site (not domain)

Tags: date, time, web

I am wondering how to determine the age of a web site (not the age of the host / domain registration) in a robust and universal way.

Take [this site](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052970204058404577110380555673036.html) as an example:

Most of the times, the age / date (December 21, 2011, in this case) appears on the site, but AFAIK there is no universal way of getting this information from the page (could be on the page, in the META-tag, header...)

If you google the headline, Google will show the age (first result; gray; so Google extracted this information somehow):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcXwo.png [I don't have privileges to embedd this as an image]

Alongside, there are other sites with the same news (i guess it's from a press agency) and Google shows the age for those as well, but not for the last one, despite its occurrence in the text (First line; *Wednesday, December 21, 2011*).

**Q1)** How to determine the age in a universal way?

**Q2)** How does Google do it? Is it just the time the URL showed up in the index? Why isn't there a date then for the last result?

**Q3)** If there is no other way then actually getting it *from* Google, how can that be done automatically for a couple of domains? After a number of automated requests, Google will block / prevent you from sending more requests. I had a look in the Google Custom Search API, but the data does not show up in the results there.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, what *is* the age of a web site? The closest I can think of is the `Last-Modified:` header from the HTTP response, but note that there are, for example, highly dynamic sites like SO where the question is not all that well-posed to start with.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that it's not a hard criterion, which makes it difficult; I guess. Last-Modified (see answer below) works, but often shows the date for the whole domain

Answer (score 0):

If the server supports it you can use the Last-Modified Header part of the HTTP-Request.

try: `curl -I http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052970204058404577110380555673036.html`

to get only the HTTP-Header of the Reply and have a look at the output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 May 2012 12:40:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
...
FastDynaPage-ServerInfo: secj2kentwap07 - Wed 05/09/12 - 08:40:10 EDT
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 May 2012 12:40:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `Last-Modified` often shows the date for the whole domain or is changing because of $foo. For the WSJ-example, it is changing; I'm getting a newer date than you now. Despite this fact, Google seems to have the correct / desired date (which is, in my example, the date of publication of the news).

Comment: I'd guess google lists the date when they found the version they've seen on their last visit for the first time. In your last example, the snippet shown contains an editorial date. They might just suppress their own date idea in that situation, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I haven't found a proper way to get the date from the URL. So I took another approach: I try to find a feed (either from the site itself or through Google) that contains that URL as an item.

Then there is a good chance that I'll either get a *pubDate* or *dc:date* which contains the date of publication. This is then usable.

Thanks for all the input.